# React Passing Data Between Components that are Nested in Same Component?

Tags: reactjs

In my situation I have a root component called App.

Inside my App component render function I have two other react components. ModalWrapper is the first component and it has a method called closeModal() which I would like to be able to call from within its child component AddUser. Is there anyway to pass this method down to addUser without moving the AddUser call to the ModalWrapper render function?

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div> 
      <ModalWrapper title="Add Member" buttonText="Add Member">
        <AddUser />
      </ModalWrapper>
    <div>
   )
}
```

Comment: What is react version?

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: Did you implement `ModalWrapper` component? If so, make it a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that passes closeModal as prop to any child component.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
 }
 closeModal(){
  alert('close Modal');
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <div>
     <ChildComponent closeModal = {this.closeModal} />
   </div>
  ); 
}
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  this.props.closeModal();
 }
 render(){
  return(<div> </div>);
 }
}
```

Let's say you have parent component and you define a function in parent component and want to use that function in to the child component. You can use parent component function in to child component by passing it via props. and call parent function in child component via props.

Comment: you can pass parent function as a props anywhere on button click, on focus anywhere you want.